# GridView onclick not working when pressed back button from 2nd Activity

Tags: android, gridview

Let us say I have two Activities. We call them activity1 and activity2.

Now activity1 has a grid view and each cell is filled with a custom layout using an adapter. The layout has an imageView and a text. Now each layout is given an ID via setTag from getView method of the adapter.

Now the activity2 contains the data based on the ID it gets from activity1. activity2 gets the ID via `getIntent().getExtra().getString("ID")` this id is then send to database to retrieve the data accordingly. OK now we know what is going on in the app.

**THE PROBLEM**

When I click any item on the gridView on activity1 it opens the activity2 successfully and the data is shown on activity2 but (here comes the problem) when I press back button activity1 opens and all the cells in the gridView stop working for onclick and only one cell works and that is the cell which was clicked in the first place. So it can be any cell but once you press it , go to activity2 and come back all the other cells do nothing onclick except the cell which cliked first.
I don't understand why this is happening.

**THE CODE**

```
public void listenToItemClick(GridView gridview)
    {
        gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(mainPanel.this , itemTypeList.class);
                Toast.makeText(mainPanel.this, "" + position + "ID:" + v.getTag(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                intent.putExtra("itemId", v.getTag() + "");
                //View target =
                TextView counter = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.action_user);
                ;
                //int cartCounter = Integer.parseInt(counter.getText() + "");
                intent.putExtra("cartCounter", counter.getText() + "");
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
```

I am calling this function in onCreate of activity1.

Comment: Could I see the code for the back button?

Comment: @DennisvanOpstal there is no code for back button. Its general android back button. I have not overriden any button.

Comment: How are you going back from activity2 to activity1 are you pressing the arrow on the top left (if there is one) or are you pressing the back button of the phone?

Comment: the back button not on top but the default back button android has on screen at the bottom with other two button in order from bottom right as "recents" , "home" , "back"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try calling `listenToItemClick()` in the `onResume()` method instead of `onCreate()`

because `onCreate()` is only called once when the activity is being created and `onResume()`is called multiple times as you can see [here](http://www.javatpoint.com/images/androidimages/Android-Activity-Lifecycle.png)

Comment: placed the function before super.onResume() and after it aswell. nothing worked.

Comment: @UzumakiNaruto Did you override the onResume() method like this:
`@Override
protected void onResume()
{
  super.onResume();
}`

Comment: yes and called the function listenToItemClicks above and below the super.onResume(). But it didnt work. after resume the grid only responds to the first cell. don't know whats wrong

Comment: I copied everything in onCreate method and pasted it in onResume() and it worked. Thanks for pitching the idea to play with onResume();

Comment: great! I'm glad that I could help